# Reactjs: Error: HomePage(...): Nothing was returned from render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I learn REACTJS, and I find one problem,  I don't know how I can fix them

*Error: HomePage: Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.*

Code Component:

```
import React from "react";

const HomePage = () =>{
    <div className="homepage">
        <div className="directory-menu">
            <div className="menu-item">
                <div className="content">
                    <h1 className="title">HATS</h1>
                    <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="menu-item">
                <div className="content">
                    <h1 className="title">JACKETS</h1>
                    <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="menu-item">
                <div className="content">
                    <h1 className="title">SNEAKERS</h1>
                    <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="menu-item">
                <div className="content">
                    <h1 className="title">WOMENS</h1>
                    <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="menu-item">
                <div className="content">
                    <h1 className="title">MENS</h1>
                    <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
};

export default HomePage;
```

Code App:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';


import HomePage from './homepage.component';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <HomePage/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So add `return` to the home component:)

```js
import React from "react";

const HomePage = () =>{
  return (
      <div className="homepage">
        <div className="directory-menu">
            <div className="menu-item">
                <div className="content">
                    <h1 className="title">HATS</h1>
                    <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="menu-item">
                <div className="content">
                    <h1 className="title">JACKETS</h1>
                    <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="menu-item">
                <div className="content">
                    <h1 className="title">SNEAKERS</h1>
                    <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="menu-item">
                <div className="content">
                    <h1 className="title">WOMENS</h1>
                    <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="menu-item">
                <div className="content">
                    <h1 className="title">MENS</h1>
                    <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
};

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: Thanks very much ! :D